# Setting a backgroundImage full height of page with React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Im trying to set a static image to be laid out on full height and width of page but it doesn't seem to work, any suggestions ?
Image and code below.

```
import Image from './image.jpg'

var containerStyle = {
    width: "100%",
    height: "400px",
    backgroundImage: `url(${Image})`,
    backgroundPosition: 'center',
    backgroundSize: 'cover',
    backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat'
};

export default function Navbar() {

return (

        <div>
            <img style={containerStyle} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
var containerStyle = {
    width: "100vw",
    height: "100vh",
    ...
};
```

Comment: Add some explanation for your code would be preferred